# Where do the DigestValues in the References of a XML Signature come from?

Tags: java, xml, w3c, w3c-validation

I have to Sign an XML file and have the Signature and the file inside the same XML. The Problem is, that I have to generate DigestValues in the References, but I am not sure where they come from. I have an example and the URI is poniting to an Element inside the same Document. But I dont know how to generate the Hash Value of these parts while also applying a transform first.

I have tried to has the elements that are inside, for example one Reference points to the KeyInfo and I tried to get the fingerprint of the Certificates, which didnt work.

I have tried to just hash the stirng of the part

I have tried XPath, which didnt work because I have to generate the DigestValue before I ouput everything as an XML

Unforunatly I cant post any Code because of confidentiality reasons, but to get a rugh understanding of what I am talikng about I am using w3c standards: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/

I either want a way to create the Elements, like the KeyInfo as a data object or a way to get the correct DigestValue of the KeyInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you create an Element you have to specify an ID attribute and tell it to be an ID-Attribute. For example:

```
Element element1 = doc.createElement("element1");
element1.setAttribute("Id", "123456789");
element1.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
```

This will make sure, that the ID will be seen as the URI when signing it.